# Providing a back link inside of a Facebook tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use `history.back()` inside of my Facebook app to go up our site hierarchy since the browser back button is obviously useless in this sort of situation. I'm using javascript to avoid having to manage history site on the backend but it's proving to be very buggy. Clicking a link with `href="javascript:history.back()"`causes the page to scroll around a couple times then actually causes `top` to go back...

Any help with this subject is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `history.back()` is not possible due to the way Facebook hacks around with the iframes that run apps. I ended up having to implement a pseudo-back link via an implementation in the server-side framework I was using.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up on this.  I was wondering what the solution would be.  Thanks for the tip.